# Infinispan vs memcached for high concurrency need

Tags: caching, memcached, infinispan

My web application maintains in memory cache of domain entities which are read/written at high frequency. To make application clustered, i need to synchronize / externalize this cache.

Which will be better option amongst memcached and infinispan considering following application facts-

- cache will be read/written at high frequency per second
- if infinispan, data need to replicated across nodes near- real time
- high concurrent write should not create conflicts issue if replication is slow.

I feel memcached will solve this purpose well since it's centralized and does not need replication delay like infinispan. Can experts provide opinion on this?

Comment: A good amount of comparison is mentioned [here](http://vschart.com/compare/jboss-infinispan/vs/memcached) which may help as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not a Memcached expert but let me tell you more about some fundamental concepts so that you could pick the best option for your use case...

First, centralized vs decentralized - if you have only one node in your system, it will be faster (as you said there is no replication). However what will happen if the node is down? Or another scenario - what will happen if the node gets full (as you said you will perform a lot of read/writes per second)? One solution for that is to use master/slave replication where writes are propagated to the slave node asynchronously. This solution will save you in case the node is down but won't do any good if the node is full (if master node is full, slave will get full a couple of minutes later).

Data consistency - if you have more than 1 node in your system, your data might get out of sync. Imagine asynchronous replication between 2 nodes and a client connected to each of them. Both clients perform a write to the same key at the same exact moment. It might seems unlikely but believe me, with highly concurrent reads and writes it will happen. The only way to solve this problem is to use synchronous replication with majority of nodes up and running (or with so called consensus).

Back to your scenario - if a broken node is not a problem for you (for example, you can switch to some other data source automatically) and your data won't grow - go ahead for 1 node solution or master/slave replication. If your data need to be strongly consistent - make sure you're doing sync replication (and possibly with transactions but you need to refer to the user manual for guidance). Otherwise I would recommend picking a more versatile solution which will allow you to add/remove nodes without taking down whole system and will have an option for sync/async replication.

From my experience, people care too much about data consistency whereas should care much more about scalability. And a final piece of advice - please define your performance criteria before evaluating any solution (something like, my writes need to take no longer than X and reads no longer than Y. Define also confidence level for your criteria (I need 99.5% of all reads to be less than X).